# Open my images in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, image, widget, flickr

I have built a widget in this page http://www.flickrbadge.com/

For my site, I wanna show nine images from my flickr account to my site, that page showed me this code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.flickr_badge_image {margin:0px;display:inline;}
.flickr_badge_image img {border: 3px solid #4D4D4D !important; padding:0px; margin:3px;}
#flickr_badge_wrapper {width:300px;text-align:left}
</style><div id="flickr_badge_wrapper"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?count=9&display=random&size=s&layout=x&source=user&user=xxxxxxxxx"></script><center><small>Created with <a href="http://www.flickrbadge.com">flickr badge</a>.</small></center></div>
```

I don't have any problem using this code, but when i make click in one of these images, i lose the last page, **i want to do a function similar like this (target="_blank")** in that script, What should i change?

apologizeme in advance if I overlook something. Any contribution is wellcome, Thanks for evaluate!

Have a great day!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jQuery just put this on the end of your page:

```
<script>
$(window).bind("load", fixImages);

function fixImages()
{
   $("#flickr_badge_wrapper a").attr("target", "_blank");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: It was an accurate solution! Thanks so much berblexer!